# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE during pgAdmin login

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, pgadmin

I hosted pgAdmin on my VM using docker compose. The docker compose yml file is provided down below.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: xyz-postgres-db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: xyz
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: xyz-pgadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5433:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: example@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: Example123
```

After this, I executes the following command to start and run the container

`docker-compose up -d`

Nows where the problem starts. The login page of pg admin loads when I try this URL (IP:5433). Screenshot down below.

[image: Login Page - pgAdmin]

After I enter the credentials and login, I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Screenshot down below.

[image: Error Screenshot after clicking login button]

What could be the issue here?

I am expecting the login to be successful and then see the UI where I can connect to my postgres db.
Somethings that I have tried was to use a different port using PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT under environment in the docker-compose.yml file.

I also tried having a stronger password. That seems desperate, but saw another SO post which suggested that as a fix.

Also tried to change the version of the image that was pulled, still the same issue.

Edit:

Some more additional information, this docker container is running on a Digital Ocean droplet and it also has an nginx configuration.